# Symfony install missing vendors libraries

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I have a fresh install of Symfony with everthing looking in-place apart from my vendors directory is empty? That is, it has 
composer and doctrine directories in it but they are empty. If I stand in my root and run the command:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
- Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
Downloading: 100%
Failed to download doctrine/lexer from dist: Could not decompress the archive, enable the PHP zip extension.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /etc/php5/php.ini
Now trying to download from source
- Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
Cloning 83893c552fd2045dd78aef794c31e694c37c0b8c



[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone git@github.com:doctrine/lexer.git via git, https, ssh protocols, aborting.

- git://github.com/doctrine/lexer.git
Cloning into '/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/symfony.local/vendor/doctrine/lexer'...
fatal: remote composer already exists.

- https://github.com/doctrine/lexer.git
fatal: destination path '/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/symfony.local/vendor/doctrine/lexer' already exists and is not an empty directory.

- git@github.com:doctrine/lexer.git
fatal: destination path '/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/symfony.local/vendor/doctrine/lexer' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

At the front end browsing to `http://symfony.local/web/`

```
Warning: require(C:\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\app\autoload.php on line 11

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes') in C:\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.local\app\autoload.php on line 11
```

Clearly it's looking for `/vendor/autoload.php` but this isn't there. Why is my vendor directory empty and how can I ensure the libraries get installed?

`$ composer update` returns:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing paragonie/random_compat (1.1.4)
Downloading: 100%
Failed to download paragonie/random_compat from dist: Could not decompress the archive, enable the PHP zip extension.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /etc/php5/php.ini
Now trying to download from source
- Installing paragonie/random_compat (1.1.4)
Cloning d762ee5b099a29044603cd4649851e81aa66cb47

[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone git@github.com:paragonie/random_compat.git via git,  https, ssh protocols, aborting.

- git://github.com/paragonie/random_compat.git
Cloning into '/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/symfony.local/vendor/paragonie/random_compat'...
fatal: remote composer already exists.

- https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat.git
fatal: destination path '/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/symfony.local/vendor/paragonie/random_compat' already exists and is not an empty directory.

- git@github.com:paragonie/random_compat.git
fatal: destination path '/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/symfony.local/vendor/paragonie/random_compat' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your PHP is not properly configured.

Adjust your `/etc/php5/php.ini` and enable the "ZIP" extension.

And the rest is probably a permissions issue, because you are using Cygwin in combination with Composer. Composer and Cygwin are not really best friends.

My suggestion: run Composer on the native Windows CLI, just for the vendor fetching part.

Comment: Using the default shell instead of Cygwin and all the libraries are coming online with `composer update`. So, Cygwin was the problem. I un-commented `extension=php_zip.dll` in `php.ini` also. Thanks Jens

Comment: I can't find ```extension=php_zip.dll``` in my ```/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini```. Should I write this line?

Comment: @JCarlos No, just installing it should work: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-unzip`

Answer (score 3):

What you want is `composer update`. It will read your `composer.json` to install all required packages. `composer install` is used for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Download and **enable the zip extention for PHP**
If you are using **PHP7.0** and use a debian base distribution (Ex: Ubuntu), **use the following to install and enable it automaticaly**

```
apt-get install php-zip
```